# What is the difference between `jtwDecode` and `jwt_decode`

Tags: typescript, jwt

I'm working on a typescript code in an angular project and am seeing that both ways of using `jwt-decode` seems to work the same way:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

and

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
```

Is there any difference between the two? Is there a preferred option between the two?

Comment: In your case, you are using a default import, meaning it was exported without a name. You could name it whatever you want and it will work. See more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import

Comment: You could try using `import { ... } from 'jwt-decode'`